# Undo a round in R

Tags: r

This is a curiousity and I highly doubt you can do what I am asking because the concept is, well silly.  If I were to round something can it be unrounded?

So:

```
x <- round(rnorm(10))
x
```

You have no idea what the original something is can you get back to the original numbers generated by `rnorm`?

I ask because when I write functions for users I often put rounding arguments in them to make display better but I always give the user control of the digits and allow independent control of digit rounding for list objects.  That makes a function full of `digits=` arguments really quickly.  I would put these arguments in the function internally if I knew the user could somehow magically re-extract the original values.  I could leave the digits as are, assign to a class and use a print method but for a list this is a pain at best.

Comment: It sounds like you really want to just round `print` (or other display) output and not the data itself.

Comment: For example, if you set `option(digits=3)` and then type `rnorm(10)` into the console, you will see fewer digits but lose no precision.

Comment: If you are specifically wanting to recover `rnorms`, you could always `set.seed` before calculating data for the user, remember the seed and then regenerate the random numbers after setting the seed again.

Comment: @seancarmody has pretty much covered it so I'll leave it for him to answer. Simply speaking, *don't round the data itself*. Rounding is a one-way thing. Round in a call to `print()`, or at the worst, round a copy of the data. You can *very approximately* undo it (e.g. by replacing the rounded data by its expectation) by making use of the known distribution and the sample information. Or you can even work out the entire distribution of each value given all the information.

Comment: You should also look into `sprintf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you round the actual data itself, in general you cannot recover it. Instead you should change the display using a custom `print` or trying something like `option(digits=3)`. In the very particular case of random number generation, you could recover the original data if you first set the seed (`set.seed`), remembered it and then re-generated the random data from the same seed.

Comment: Ahh I never thought about that in a print. I don't like to make global changes but you could record the current `options()$digits` and assign it, change to what ever digits I feel is appropriate and `print`, and change `options` back so no global change occurs. Good answer, I do this already with `options()$width` so it really should have occurred to me to do the same thing, but it didn't :) thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `sprintf` to just modify how things get printed.

```
myfun <- function(){
    x <- rnorm(3)
    print(sprintf("%.3f", x))
    invisible(x)
}

out <- myfun()
#[1] "-0.527" "0.226"  "-0.168"
out
#[1] -0.5266562  0.2262599 -0.1680460
```

Comment: I'll have to play with this more but from what you're saying it seems that I may not have to create specific print methods for every function in a package but use this inside of the functions themselves. +1

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't resist doing it the hard way...

```
x<-runif(100)*10
z<-round(x,2)
y<-x-z
```